# put ajax response to input parameters (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

1) I have a input field as follows

```
<label>Size:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="data.Size" ng-init="data.Size='10000000'" />

<label>Number:</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="data.Number" ng-init="data.Number='10'" />
```

As you can see, the size and number have been initialized with ng-init.

2) Now i have a ajax call to server posting this input parameters

```
var submitData = "=" + JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL2,
            data: submitData
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.Info);

});
```

The response of this ajax function contains new values for Size and Number input field. 
console to response.Info gives this output in object form as shown below.

[Object]

0: Object

size:10000

number:5

Now, i need to pass this values to the input fields so that the values reflect the new values which we get by calling ajax call as shown above.

can someone please let me know how to bind these two and display it to the user

Comment: "=" + <-- why is there an equals before the data?

Comment: @epascarello- have tried other ways to stringify the data but didnt work for me. putting "=" works fine. dont know the actual reason why it has to be like that

Comment: But that makes zero sense. If it works, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ng-init` here, you only need to bind response object to `$scope.data`, Also you should use `$.ajax`

**Code**

```
var submitData = "=" + JSON.stringify(data);
      $http({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL2,
            data: submitData
      }).then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            console.log(data.Info);
            $scope.data = data.Info;
      });
}
```

Comment: When i write $scope.data = data.Info, it refreshes the page and null values gets shown on those fields. any update on why it does this kind of behavior